# angular 6 unittest, observable of() is synchronous

Tags: angular, jasmine, rxjs, karma-jasmine, rxjs6

had to delete a previous question in case you are wondering, to reformulate:

I have this component set up:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-async',
  templateUrl: './async.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./async.component.scss']
})
export class AsyncComponent implements OnInit {

  title$: Observable<string>;
  constructor(private stringService: AsyncStringService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.title$ = this.stringService.getString();
  }
}
```

where `AsyncStringService.getString` is this:

```
getString(): Observable<string>
```

and the template for the component is:

```
<h1 id="title">{{title$ | async}}</h1>
```

I want to test the components behaviour with jasmines async features, but my tests also work if I do not take any async continuation into account:

```
describe('AsyncComponent', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AsyncComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ AsyncComponent ],
      providers: [ AsyncStringService ]
    })
    .compileComponents().then(() =>
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AsyncComponent));

  }));

  it('should not have resolved observable immedeatly', () => {
    const spy = spyOn(fixture.debugElement.injector.get(AsyncStringService), 'getString')
      .and.returnValue(of( 'value 1'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#title')).nativeElement.innerText).toEqual('value 1');
  });

  it('should have all observables resolved in whenStable', async(() => {
    const spy = spyOn(fixture.debugElement.injector.get(AsyncStringService), 'getString')
      .and.returnValue(of( 'value 1'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#title')).nativeElement.innerText).toEqual('value 1');
    });
  }));


  it('should have all observables resolved when ticking', fakeAsync(() => {
    const spy = spyOn(fixture.debugElement.injector.get(AsyncStringService), 'getString')
      .and.returnValue(of( 'value 1'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();

    expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#title')).nativeElement.innerText).toEqual('value 1');
  }));
});
```

all three tests succeed, I want the spy to return an observable that fails the first test, as it does not take asynchronicity into account.

Also, any hints if I use these features (async / fakeAsync) incorrectly are appreciated!

edit.:

I tried of('value 1').pipe(delay(100)), which causes all tests to fail. I assume this is somehow connected to the async pipe not being seen by the async/fakeAsync flows?

Edit.:

I got the synchronous task to fail, while done() and async() pass by returning `timer(10).pipe(map(() => 'value 1'))` from my spy.

the fake async test however behaves strange:

it passes if I check the observable values in subscribers, even if I do not call tick() at all - so no time should pass and the time should never emit a value.

and calling tick(100), which should make the time(10) to emit, does NOT cause the value to land in the template outside the subscribers.

```
 it('should have all observables resolved when ticking the appropriate amount of time', fakeAsync(() => {
    const spy = spyOn(fixture.debugElement.injector.get(AsyncStringService), 'getString')
      .and.returnValue(timer(10).pipe(map(() => 'value 1')));
    fixture.componentInstance.ngOnInit();
    fixture.componentInstance.title$.subscribe(value => expect(value).toEqual('value 1'));
    fixture.componentInstance.title$.subscribe(() => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#title')).nativeElement.innerText).toEqual('value 1');
    });
    tick(100); // this does nothing
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#title')).nativeElement.innerText).toEqual('value 1');
    discardPeriodicTasks();
  }));
```

Comment: Have a look at [rxjs-marbles](https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-marbles)

Comment: This is the most trivial test to show a usecase for fakeAsync or async + whenStable I could come up with, and the test also works without using those built in features. I think I am doing something wrong here and not that the 3 ways to test async code in jasmine all make no sense and require the use of marbels which does not even mention them in the docs or jasmine examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my mocked observables to be async by passing in the async scheduler as the 2nd parameter to of():

```
import {async as _async} from 'rxjs/scheduler/async';

var stub$ = of(stub, _async);
```